# Long Multilayered Puzzle: What's the animal?

Tags: knowledge

This is a puzzle I made myself!

**What's the puzzle?**
You will be presented with an image containing a puzzle, then another one, then  yet another one, and so on.
Here's the first image:
[image]

**Wait, doesn't that count as multiple puzzles?**
...I guess it does.

**How to find the next image then? Please help!**
Here's some information <s>since it's pretty much impossible to figure out yourself</s>:

- All images are posted in [Postimages](https://postimages.org/), and you'll need to find the next image's URL from the current image.
- In each image is a puzzle that yields a sequence of letters and numbers. The next image URL can be determined by using that sequence in the format `https://postimg.cc/{sequence}`. Read that again if it's unclear
- In the bottom left of each image are formattings that show:

  - Which part of the sequence is filled, and
  - Capitalization/format – **`U`** for uppercase, **`l`** for lowercase, and **`n`** for number (see the first image for visualization).
- The formattings have blanks – fill those in with the puzzle's solutions! Try again if the URL doesn't lead to a valid image.
- It technically can lead to a valid image even if the answer's wrong, but that's *very very* unlikely.

**Wait, can you give me an example?**
I originally included examples but they're too long, so I'll add them if/when someone asks.

**I can just find the URLs with brute-force, right?**
Yes, technically, but that won't be fun.

**Can I have some hints? Please???**
The answer depends on whether you count this as a hint, but...

> The puzzles don't involve [ROTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) or ciphers or encrypting/decrypting stuff <s>because I'm bad at them</s>.

Also...

> **Most** of the time, you don't need to look for small details.

You're welcome

**How many images are there?**
There are less than 20. The last image's puzzle will give the ultimate answer to my question!

**How do I know if my answer's correct?**
As I said before... The answer is an animal, and is 3-6 letters long.

Some clarifications (so the answer doesn't feel unfair):

- The answer could be the animal's "nickname" or its fancy Latin scientific name.
- The animal can be either fact or fiction (meaning it can be real or fake).

**Hey, that's my answer!**
Good! Now, write exactly 14 paragraphs describing how you got to that answer. Also, incomplete answers are fine

**But somebody else has posted [78.57% of the answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120992/84250), what should I do?**
Well... you can either edit that answer to include the remaining 21.43% *(only do this if you want to spoil the fun for [@theozh](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/83038/theozh))*, or comment on that answer, or post an answer yourself! They're all perfectly fine.
You can also say nothing and wait for others to solve it, give them a small hint, or mislead them by giving a false hint *(recommended by 9/10 doctors)*.

**Why <s>is</s> <s>was</s> <s>is</s> was there a bounty?**
...I guess [@JGibbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16466/jgibbers) wants to draw more attention to this question. Appreciate that, thanks!

I set another bounty to hopefully get someone solve the whole thing. Besides, I don't mind losing my rep points

## ⚠️VERY IMPORTANT⚠️

I made at least 1 unintended mistake . So, correction(s):

- In the third image, the format should have a capital `F` instead of a lowercase `f`.

Second-lastly, as [people have really short attention spans nowadays](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121110/paid-partnerships), I applaud you for reading this far (unless you just skipped through everything I typed above)

Alright, that's all. Have fun and **GOOD LUCK!**

Comment: If your puzzle is dependent on a lot of off-site images, is it possible to transfer them to i.stack.imgur? (Probably not if you've set up the URLs, though...) That's SE's integrated image-hosting service. See the tag [[tag:imgur-maze]] for some other puzzles like this, although usually shorter.

Comment: SE has a contract with imgur to ensure that images will be hosted forever, regardless of any change imgur makes to their free public service. Whereas other sites, even if they promise permanent hosting, might go under or start clearing out images to save space. That means imgur-hosted puzzles are immune to breaking due to link rot, but we can't guarantee that for other hosting services.

Comment: Also, using the SE image-hosting service enables people who have restricted internet access (that blocks other image-hosting sites) to still be able to view the images.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for telling me  (Deleted some of my comments so it's not too cluttered)

Comment: Bounty goes to whoever has posts answer that goes the furthest btw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animal is

> the [**OPPIH**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SSnQBtaq4) (warning: slightly gross video)

theozh's answer gets as far as Puzzle 9

> https://postimg.cc/8jRCMZSM

A couple people solved Puzzle 9 in the comments on that answer:

> The letters are country codes of adjacent countries:
>  TDCFCD: Chad, Central African Republic, DRC
>  TMAFPK: Turkmenistan, Afghanistan, Pakistan
>  VE__SR: Venezuala, _____, Suriname
>  Guyana is in between them so we have the letters GY.
>  The black queen hints at the Queen's gambit, where black's only move is d5
>  So our url for Puzzle 10 is https://postimg.cc/7GYdmv50

Puzzle 10

> There is a Greek flag and two fractions, 5/8 and 2/3. The Greek alphabet has 24 letters. 5/8 of 24 is 15 and 2/3 of 24 is 16. The 15th and 16th letters are omicron and pi. At first I mistakenly thought this meant OP as in "original poster" but that led me to [OP's user page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/84250/thepuzzler-or-rather-apuzzler) where there is evidence of quite an affinity for the "[oppih](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SSnQBtaq4)"(warning: slightly gross video) which could be spelled omicron pi if pronounced "oh" "pi".

Comment: I approve. Some people thought **really** far (like looking at country flags' aspect ratio and even looking at Greek islands), but in the end you did it. Good job, hope you liked it! Disclaimers coming soon  _(Side note: had you posted roughly 2 hours earlier, you would've gotten the +50 bounty)_

Comment: Actually, the word I was looking for is _clarification_, not _disclaimer_ haha.

Comment: Oh wow this was one of the first thoughts I had but I couldn't piece together the animal. Good job!

Answer (score 6):

Not a complete solution...

**Puzzle 1:**

> Looks like a QWERTY keyboard.The sequence of the letters is not clear, but first trial would be `qw1` `BXL___BL` `...lln..` https://postimg.cc/BXLqw1BL

**Puzzle 2:**

> The atom model directs to the periodic system of the elements. Two numbers 111,48 mirrored. Element numbers 48 and 111 are Cadmium (Cd) and Roentgenium (Rg) Reversed and lower case makes gr and dc. `__J__JTz` `ll.ll...` https://postimg.cc/grJdcJTz

**Puzzle 3:**

> Italy in the center of a map. Approx. on top of Rome the number 1515. This leads to the Roman number MDXV. `4_fvb___`  `.l...Ull` (with the correction f-->F). https://postimg.cc/4mFvbDxv

**Puzzle 4:**

> On first sight it looks like a clock with 12 subdivisions. What does ENE mean? ENE is e.g. a romanian last name or the airport code of an airport in Indonesia. So maybe some letters of numbers nine and six in Romanian or Indonesian? However, apparently, this should be a compass rose (but shouldn't this have 16 subdivisions?) and ENE stands for East-North-East. The arrow to 1 points to West (W) and South (S) or apparently (SSS). Take the first letter of W and the second and third letter of SSS. `18__mv_T` `..Ul..l.` https://postlmg.cc/18WsmvsT

**Puzzle 5:**

> Six times F, 0, 1/3 makes #FFFFFF in RGB colors "white" and #000000 is "black" and 1/3 * 6 is 2. `_ypj8_h_` `l....U.n` https://postimg.cc/wypj8Bh2

**Puzzle 6:**

> No idea what the first image should represent, some pads or a door stopper...? Well, The puzzle text has some typos: gues > guess, bob > job, nect > next. Take the correct letters, i.e. s,j,x. A card deck has typically 52 cards. `___V_Lq_` `UUl.n..n` https://postimg.cc/SJxV5Lq2

**Puzzle 7:**

> A map which only shows blue. This could be a zoom-in into an ocean, i.e. sea. Chess... the position of the black king (g8) or the white bishop (h7)? Doesn't work. Black must have done a castling which is noted as `0-0` or sometimes as `O-O`... no idea...

For the time being I'm stuck here.

> ok, apparently these should be the Marshall Islands, two letter code (mh) (I overlooked OP's comment on 2-letter code), however, I couldn't find any map which resembles the given image, so this was more a trial and error. Chess: last move white Bishop (B) to h7. `___n__FM` `lll.ln..` https://postimg.cc/mhbnh7FM

**Puzzle 8:**

> Except for Clint Eastwood I had to reverse image search the other people. 1. Clint Eastwood, 2. Robert Downey Jr., 3. Snoop Dogg, 4. Lionel Richie. They are all US-citizens. About the huge number... it is in the list of the on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences https://oeis.org/A002000/list   but how further? `8__C_ZS_` `.lU.U..U`. If first part is maybe `uS`, how to make two letters out of this big number?

Stuck again...

> Apparently, I consulted the only Wikipedia language page where Lionel Richie was *not* listed as Jr. Thanks to the hint from @Sconibulus it is not US, but Jr. For the second part, I have no idea how to reduce the big number (similar to Puzzle 3 as @Sconibulus suggets) down to two letters. So, wild guessing led to MM, but why MM=2000? `8__C_ZS_` `.lU.U..U` https://postimg.cc/8jRCMZSM

**Puzzle 9:**

> No clue where to start. A lot of letters. First guess would be the first letters of the words of a well known quote or song or whatever. The second drawing, no idea what this should be: a strange meeple? a pawn in a game? How to get from this to a letter and a number? Game over...? I'm also not sure what this Easter egg in the lower right corner should hint to.

Stuck again...

Comment: Very nice!! I'll add clarifications when there's a complete solution. Good luck continuing  Also, **rot13** (Gur znc qbrfa'g ercerfrag n frn) if you want a slight hint.

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler haha, now I looked more carefully, I thought this was dust on my screen. I will check again.

Comment: FWIW here's the FEN of the position in puzzle 7: rnbq1rk1/ppp2ppB/4p3/b2n4/3P4/P1N2N2/1PPBQPPP/R3K2R b KQ - 0 1

Comment: @DanDan0101 hmm... more hint(s): **rot13** _V qvqa'g fcrpvsl jung gb ybbx sbe va gur purff cbfvgvba, fb trggvat gur SRA vf haarprffnel (ernyyl)  Nyfb, bhg bs gur 5 oynaxf va gur frdhrapr, bayl gur svefg 2 ner sebz gur znc_. Also, theozh... **rot13** _Unun, lbh gubhtug gubfr jrer qhfg? Ubcrshyyl gung qbrfa'g vafhyg nal vaunovgnagf bs gung, ree, ertvba. Ba gur oevtug fvqr, V thrff lbhe fperra'f pyrnare guna lbh gubhtug!_ (In case you haven't figured it out )

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler **rot13** Gur vaunovgnagf bs ??? ubcrshyyl jba'g gnxr vg nzvff gung V qvq abg erpbtavmr gurve vfynaqf. Fb, gur vqrn jnf gb gnxr gur 3-yrggre pbqr bs gung vfynaq pbhagel. Jryy, V pbhyqa'g svaq gurfr vfynaq, arvgure ol fpnaavat gur bprnaf abe ol erirefr vzntr frnepu. Znlor V'z fgvyy ba gur jebat genpx.

Comment: **rot13** Jnvg, qb lbh zrna 2-yrggre pbhagel pbqrf? (V fnvq rneyvre gur svefg gjb yrggref pbzr sebz gur znc.) Naljnl, V jbhyqa'g tb sbe erirefr vzntr frnepu fvapr gur vfynaqf ner fb gval  Gur znc fubjf gur jubyr pbhagel, fb lbh pna vzzrqvngryl ryvzvangr ovt vfynaq pbhagevrf (naq whfg frnepu gur zncf bs fznyyre barf). Nabgure uvag: vg'f abg va gur Nzrevpnf. V ncbybtvmr sbe znxvat guvf gbb uneq :)

Comment: for puzzle 8, each of them is second of that name, for the first letters, then puzzle 3 again for the other set.

Comment: Hmm, are you stuck somewhere now? I'm guessing puzzle 9, haha. Also, @Sconibulus I approve 

Comment: **rot13** (Jryy... 2000 ersref gb gur BRVF. Nyfb, ersreevat gb n fbat jbhyq znxr gur chmmyr yvgrenyyl vzcbffvoyr. N cerivbhf chmmyr hfrf gur yrggref va n fvzvyne jnl, fb qba'g guvax gbb sne bhgfvqr gur obk unun.) [Hint](https://lichess.org/) for the second image, good luck! You're almost there.

Comment: You don’t know how MM is related to 2000? You are not in rot13(Ebzr)!

Comment: @1357924680a of course I know that, but I did not make the link from the OEIS index (instead of the number itself) to two letters. Well, for this Ebzr is always good. I also didn't expect the same principle twice in the "same" Puzzle.

Comment: P9: yrggref ner gevcyrgf bs pbhagel pbqrf, cvrpr vf oynpx Dhrra'f Cnja, no idea how to start on the last one though

Comment: @Sconibulus nice!! Now, no hints for the last one. I'm **very sure** someone can do it _(though that doesn't mean it's easy)_ 

Comment: I have also solved P9, but to be honest just after a bit of guessing. I thought (gur frpbaq cneg jnf qsbhe fvapr gung'f gur dhrra'f cnja tnzr). Can you explain why this wasn't the solution?

Comment: @PattuX - (qsbhe jbhyq or pbeerpg sbe gur juvgr cnja. guvf bar vaqrrq ybbxf n yvggyr qnexre gb zr, guhf qsvir znxrf frafr.

nynf, v'z fghpx ng gur "terrx sbezhyn". gevrq fbzr yrggre-/ahzorerkpunatr ohg qvqa'g svaq gur evtug fgneg. be zvtug or ehaavat va n jebat qverpgvba.)

Comment: Oh, yes that makes sense. For the last one, my first thought was about (nfcrpg engvbf bs syntf. gjb gb guerr vf irel pbzzba (vapyhqvat Terrpr), naq svir gb rvtug vf hfrq va svir qvssrerag pbhagevrf. Ohg V qba'g xabj ubj bar jbhyq pbagvahr sebz urer.)

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler Is it intended that the last riddle does not give a pattern? Another idea that came to mind, is that (gur senpgvbaf fgneg n frdhrapr. n pnaqvqngr sbe n frdhrapr jbhyq or gur engvbf bs pbafrphgvir svobanppv ahzoref, nxn gur tbyqra envb, be nf n terrx yrggre: cuv. ohg ntnva, ab vqrn ubj gb trg gb na 8 yrggre yvax sebz gurer.)

Comment: @PattuX actually, no need to get a link! The answer to that puzzle _is_ the animal. Won't comment on the idea just yet, no hints unless someone insists. Good luck 

Comment: @toybaer good luck too! _(and sorry for the notifications @theozh)_

Comment: You're right about the pawn. Now you will have to figure out the pbhagevrf!

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler N ybatfubg thrff: vf gur nafjre "xrn"? V gbbx n znc bs Terrpr, zrnfherq nccebkvzngryl svir-rvtuguf npebff naq gjb-guveqf qbja, naq vg ybbxrq yvxr gurer jnf na vfynaq pnyyrq Xrn gurer. Gung svgf jvgu gur pyhr "gur nafjre vf na navzny 3-6 yrggref ybat"

Comment: @JS1 wow, that's a pretty cool coincidence! I would've provided less ambiguous clues if that was indeed the answer, though. Good try 

Comment: If nobody else answers _(is it really that hard?)_, you get another free 50 rep points. You're welcome :)

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler sorry, this is the StackExchange bounty system which I dislike in such cases, i.e. if you give a bounty to attract more attention, the system will give the bounty automatically to the answer with the most votes, independent if it is complete, helpful or useful. I had this case the other way round myself several times. And sorry, I have no idea about P9. If anybody else has an idea, please post it as an answer. I will not be offended.

Comment: @theozh hmm, why are you apologizing? I know you'd get the bounty either way, but it's not your fault nobody else answered (also, I manually awarded the bounty to you). Besides, the difficulty's quite inconsistent, so of course I understand if you aren't interested to go any further! You're too polite. 

Answer (score 0):

## Good job, everyone!

First, to the people who contributed in solving this:

- [@theozh](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/83038/theozh) [(puzzles 1-7)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120992)
- [@Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297/sconibulus) (puzzles [8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120986/long-multilayered-puzzle-whats-the-animal/121406#comment337589_120992), [9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120986/long-multilayered-puzzle-whats-the-animal/121406#comment337589_120992))
- [@caPNCApn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156/capncapn) [(puzzle 10)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121406)

...and to those who stopped by:

- [@DanDan0101](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78610/dandan0101)
- [@1357924680a](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/83018/1357924680a)
- [@PattuX](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42446/pattux) (extra credit for thinking about [sequences](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120986/long-multilayered-puzzle-whats-the-animal#comment337867_120992) and even [flag ratios](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120986/long-multilayered-puzzle-whats-the-animal#comment337868_120992), that's creative!)
- [@toybaer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/81241/toybaer)
- [@JS1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4479/js1) (extra credit for thinking about [the map of Greece](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120986/long-multilayered-puzzle-whats-the-animal#comment338527_120992) (and even finding an actual animal), that's also creative!)

## Clarifications

**Puzzle 4:**

> *However, apparently, this should be a compass rose (but shouldn't this have 16 subdivisions?) and ENE stands for East-North-East.*
>
>  **Correct!** Of course, putting 16 subdivisions would make it much more obvious–so I decided to use a clock instead.

> *The arrow to 1 points to West (W) and South (S) or apparently (SSS).*
>
>  Actually, it's just **S**. The **2,3** bit tells you that S is the second and third letter

**Puzzle 6:**

> *No idea what the first image should represent, some pads or a door stopper...?*
>
>  Actually, those are three blank Scrabble tiles (which refer to three letters)! Image taken from [here](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PocketScrabble.JPG) (manually edited).

**Puzzle 8:**

> *So, wild guessing led to MM, but why MM=2000?*
>
>  Well, that's because the number is in OEIS A002000 (I also pointed this out in a comment).

**Puzzle 9:**

> *I'm also not sure what this Easter egg in the lower right corner should hint to.*
>
>  Exactly! I intentionally put it there to make you overthink. You're welcome :)

> *The black queen hints at the Queen's gambit, where black's only move is d5*
>
>  Actually... It refers to the [Queen's Pawn Game](https://lichess.org/opening/Queens_Pawn_Game/d4_d5) (hence the **GAME** text), where black plays d5.

**Puzzle 10:**

> *[...] that led me to [OP's user page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/84250/thepuzzler-or-rather-apuzzler) where there is evidence of quite an affinity for the "[oppih](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SSnQBtaq4)"...*
>
>  Indeed! The hint was in my profile. *(Also, if it's not clear enough, the "I really really like oppihs" bit is actually a joke. I'm not an insane person obsessed with oppihs*  *)*

Alright, hope you enjoyed this puzzle! Thanks for stopping by.