# Paid partnerships

Tags: word-property

The mods aren't looking, so I'm selling paid sponsorships to the highest bidder. My business model takes advantage of the attention spans in today's fast-paced environment. For example, I can write whatever I want in this sentence because nobody is going to bother reading this far down the paragraph. That's how I'll smuggle in advertisements without anyone noticing. Below is a list of brands I'm currently partnered with, along with some that I'm not.

I also have standing offers from **Harvard University**, **Princeton University** and **Yale University**, of which I'm going to accept only one. Can you guess which one I'm going to choose?

[image: Paid partnership: Bing, Budweiser, Caterpillar, Coca-Cola, Ford, Jack Daniels, Porsche, Sprite, Vans "Off the Wall". No paid partnership: Google, Guinness, John Deere, Pepsi, Toyota, Johnnie Walker, Ferrari, Fanta, New Balance.]

Comment: Flagging as "Spam: Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation".  Oh, wait, it does.  Never mind, then.

Comment: THIS mod is looking now. (And likes it. Nice puzzle!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to the fast pace of life to-day, no-one will hear and get words of

> more than one syllable.

As such, smart ad-folk know to work with firms with real salt-of-the-Earth

> names like Bing, Bud, Cat, Coke, Ford, Jack, Porsche, Sprite, and Vans

and not those firms like Google, Guinness, John Deere, Pepsi, Toyota, Johnnie Walker, Ferrari, Fanta, or New Balance.

As such, you'll go with

> Yale, the only one of these universities with a monosyllabic name.

Comment: Quite so! Well done.

Comment: Wait, why monosyllabic names? I read the whole last paragraph, I don't get it!

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler ROT13: Gur "cnvq cnegarefuvc" oenaq anzrf ner, be pna or nooerivngrq gb, zbabflyynovp anzrf, juvpu ner zragvbarq va gur frpbaq cnentencu. (Wnpx = Wnpx Qnavryf pna or sbhaq va Jvxgvbanel. Cbefpur orvat cebabhaprq "cbefu" engure guna "cbe-fun" vf nyfb nggrfgrq gb ol Jvxgvbanel. Png = Pngrecvyyne vf va Jvxvcrqvn. Naq V'yy nffhzr lbh'er snzvyvne jvgu Pbxr.)

Comment: @oAlt yeah... that's the joke haha, having a **really** short attention span and skipping everything to read only the last paragraph. Appreciate your consideration 

Comment: Mmmh, Porsche is definitely a 2-syllable word in its native German. Not sure how it counts as monosyllabic in English if Google doesn't count.

Comment: @quarague Lots of English-speakers shorten the German /ˈpɔʁʃə/ to the monosyllable /pɔ(ɹ)ʃ/ colloquially, so much so that it's the first-listed pronunciation on the [Wiktionary page](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Porsche) for Porsche. I've not yet heard a monosyllablic pronunciation of Google; in my experience it's always /ˈɡuːɡ(ə)l/ for anglophones.

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler I freaking knew it, I had a feeling I missed something :P thanks for the clarification :) (I'll still leave it up there though for people who may want more details)

Comment: @oAlt haha yeah, I hope it isn't a spoiler (forgot to rot13 it )

Comment: First time I read this answer, I didn't even realize the constraint you had put on your writing (outside of the spoiler blocks). Well done.

Comment: @msh210 Thank you, you're too kind. I find that the short words quite snap, don't you? They lend an air of haste – a sense of need – to what you write. It grants some strange *je ne sais quoi*, a spark of that group of French scribes from days gone by. It is all a lot of fun :-)

Comment: So I guess that answers the question in the back of my head as to whether "Jafe" is pronounced "Jayf" or "Jah-fay"...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman see https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe?tab=profile

Comment: @msh210 Ah, I was wrong on both guesses.  Oh well...

Comment: @ThePuzzler-orratherAPuzzler (nah it's probably fine)